# My localhost posts this message: Error: Rendered fewer hooks than expected. This may be caused by an accidental early return statement

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Here is my code that is relevant for this issue, I cant figure out why I get the error message. This is the error message:  Error: Rendered fewer hooks than expected. This may be caused by an accidental early return statement.

I  dont think I return anything early and I have tried everything I can think of.

The useSummify and useSummifyOnce where added to try to solve this problem but it did not help.

```
const useSummify = ({ data, month, segment }) => {
  const sum = useMemo(() => {
    if (!data) {
      return 0;
    }

    if (month === 'Totalt') {
      const totalSumAllMonths = Object.values(data).reduce((acc, monthData) => {
        return (
          acc +
          monthData.reduce(
            (monthAcc, obj) => monthAcc + (segment === 'rut' ? obj.betalinfo || 0 : obj.total_sum || 0),
            0
          )
        );
      }, 0);
      return totalSumAllMonths;
    }

    const selectedMonthData = data[month] || [];
    const totalSumSelectedMonth = selectedMonthData.reduce(
      (acc, obj) => acc + (segment === 'rut' ? obj.betalinfo || 0 : obj.total_sum || 0),
      0
    );
    return totalSumSelectedMonth;
  }, [data, month, segment]);

  const roundedSum = parseInt(sum.toFixed(0), 10);

  return roundedSum;
};

const Summify = ({ data, month, segment }) => {
  const sum = useSummify({data, month, segment})
  return <p>{sum} kr</p>
}

const Lengthify = ({ data, month }) => {
  const totalLength = useMemo(() => {
    if (month === 'Totalt') {
      const lengthTotal = data
        ? Object.values(data).reduce((acc, monthData) => acc + (Array.isArray(monthData) ? monthData.length : 0), 0)
        : 0;
      return lengthTotal;
    }
    return data[month].length;
  }, [data, month]);
  return <p>{totalLength} st</p>;
};

const Dividify = ({ numerator, denominator, month, segment }) => {
  const numeratorSum = useMemo(() => useSummify({ data: numerator, month, segment }), [numerator, month, segment]);
  const denominatorSum = useMemo(() => useSummify({ data: denominator, month, segment }), [denominator, month, segment]);

  const percentage = useMemo(() => {
    if (!numeratorSum || !denominatorSum || denominatorSum === 0) {
      return <div>0%</div>;
    }

    const quotient = (numeratorSum / denominatorSum) * 100;
    return <div>{quotient.toFixed(2) + '%'}</div>;
  }, [numeratorSum, denominatorSum]);

  return <div>{percentage}</div>;
};

const useSummifyOnce = ({ data }) => {
  const sum = useMemo(() => {
    if (!data) {
      return 'wrong';
    }

    const totalSum = Object.values(data).reduce((acc, item) => {
      return acc + (item.betalinfo || 0 );
    }, 0);

    return totalSum;
  }, [data]);

  const roundedSum = parseInt(sum.toFixed(0), 10);

  return roundedSum;
};

const SummifyOnce = ({ data }) => {
  const sum = useSummifyOnce({data})
  return <p>{sum}</p>;
};

const DividifyOnceMemoized = React.memo(({ numerator, denominator }) => {
  const numeratorSum = useMemo(() => useSummifyOnce({ data: numerator }), [numerator]);
  const denominatorSum = useMemo(() => useSummifyOnce({ data: denominator }), [denominator]);

  const percentage = useMemo(() => {
    if (!numeratorSum || !denominatorSum || denominatorSum === 0) {
      return <div>0%</div>;
    }

    const quotient = (numeratorSum / denominatorSum) * 100;
    return <div>{quotient.toFixed(2) + '%'}</div>;
  }, [numeratorSum, denominatorSum]);

  return <div>{percentage}</div>;
});


const App = () => {
  const { isError: getDealsError, isLoading: getDealsLoading } = api.app.collections.getDeals.useQuery(undefined, {
    refetchOnWindowFocus: false
  });

  const { data: removeNoCollectingOutcomeData } = api.app.collections.removeNoCollectingOutcome.useQuery(undefined, {
    refetchOnWindowFocus: false
  });

  const { data: allUnpaidData } = api.app.collections.allUnpaid.useQuery(undefined, { refetchOnWindowFocus: false });

  const months = removeNoCollectingOutcomeData ? Object.keys(removeNoCollectingOutcomeData) : [];
  const allMonths = ['Totalt', ...months];
  const [selectedMonth, setSelectedMonth] = useState(allMonths[0]);
  const [selectedSegment, setSelectedSegment] = useState('ejrut');
  const router = useRouter();


  if (getDealsLoading) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>;
  }

  if (getDealsError) {
    return <div>Error loading data</div>;
  }

  return (...)
```

I want to be able to save changes in localhost without encountering this error.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).